# Contact Form 7 crushes my slider

Tags: jquery, slider, typeerror, flexslider

i have a problem. There is a slider at my site, called 'flexslider'. It perfectly works... I installed Contact Form 7 and the slider has broken.
In console appears this error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'flexslider'
I know that can be caused by including jQuery twice.

Site: avramch.host-ed.me/wp/

Comment: Can you change it to a $(window).load() function?

Comment: Whad do you mean?) Like this?
`$( document ).load(function( $ ) {
  $('#top-slider').flexslider({
    directionNav: false,
    animation: 'fade',
    controlsContainer: '.flexslider'
  });     
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know when it is done.

Add `$(window).on('load', function()...` to your function. Like this:

```
<script>
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#top-slider').flexslider({
      directionNav: false,
      animation: 'fade',
      controlsContainer: '.flexslider'
    });     
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Turns out `$(window).load(function() { ... });` is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). I have updated the answer above to take this into account.